# more than 1 HttpPost is activating

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am making a page where I'd like to be able to have several different actions happening depending on what is being done.

for instance I have a dropdown where I want different forms to be loaded in to the page depending on the selection in the dropdown.

Currently I'm doing it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#subject').on("change", function (e) {
          e.preventDefault();
          var selectedVal = $('#subject').val();
          $.ajax({
              url: "ContactUs/GetForm",
              type: "POST",
              data: { searchValue: selectedVal },
              async: true,
              success: function (data) {
                  $('#renderForms').empty();
                  $('#renderForms').append(data);                  
              },
              error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                  alert("An error has occured!!! " + xhr.status + " && " + xhr.responseText);
              }
          });
      }; etc...
```

this hits the following method no problem

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetForm(string searchValue)
{
//my code here
    return PartialView("_Bills",contactModel.contactBillsModel);
}
```

However when I click on it also hit the following method which is not my intention.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Contact_Portal.Models.ContactViewModel contactModel)
{
     return View(contactModel);
}
```

How do I prevent this behaviour ?

the last HttpPost I'm using in a button in the partial page like this

```
<input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
```

**Edit:**
Adding Additional Information per requested.

the view with the dropdown

```
@model WebPortal.Models.FormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "multiple forms";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>multiple forms</h2>

<label>My selection is...  </label>
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.contactSelectListItems, new List<SelectListItem>
    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "option 1", Value="option 1"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "option 2", Value="option 2"},
                        new SelectListItem() {Text = "option 3", Value="option 3"},
                         new SelectListItem() {Text = "option 4", Value="option 4"}
    }, "--choose--", new { id = "subject", @class="dropdown-item"})
<div id="renderForms">

</div>
```

one of the views with the forms:

```
@model WebPortal.Models.AformViewModel


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>A Form</h4>
        <hr />
        <div id="InfoBox" class="form-group col-md-20">
            Remember to fill out this text with relevant text.
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <!--@Html.Action("Index", "ContactUs")-->
                        <input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the `select` contained in a `form`? If so what's the action of that form? Are you submitting it?

Comment: What exactly is inside the partial view? Does it have any initialization scripts, e.g. it could be simulating a button click in order to populate the data for the first time.

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect what you asked of me
@RoryMcCrossan However the simple answer is no the select is outside the form as the form is in a partial view and the select is in the main view

Comment: @JohnWu As well it is updated to reflect your request.

Comment: Because you have `@Html.Action("Index", "ContactUs")` in the view which calls that method (note that `<!--   -->` does not comment it out - for that it would need to be surrounded in `@*  *@`)

Comment: Well that solves the first one but now I have the same problem with the input it is going to the wrong action in the controller first. @StephenMuecke

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you are saying

Comment: I've posted an answer that solves my problem. From reading that I think my intentions should be clear @StephenMuecke ? if you or anyone else have a better solution I am all ears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I have a solution thou I'm not really happy with it but it works.

this is what I've done since posting my question:
I've changed on request from Stephen Muecke this part here:

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <!--@Html.Action("Index", "ContactUs")-->
                        <input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

to

```
 <div class="form-group form-group-sm col-sm-6">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-9">
                            <input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and after that It removed my problem with activating both my HttpPost Actions GetForm and Index(viewmodel)

but I got the new problem of the submit button activating the GetForm action instead of the Index(viewmodel) action.
So because of this I changed my submit button to the following

```
 <input id="Send" type="submit" value="Send" formaction=@Url.Action("Index","ContactUs") class="btn btn-default" />
```

this change solved my problem for now but I feel that the input submit button now is now not inline with the ideas behind unobtrusive event handling.

**Edit:**

instead of the above submit button line I added this to the html form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ContactUs"))
```

Comment: You need to add the action and controller name in the `BeginForm()` method - `@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "ContactUs"))` - if you do not it posts to the method with the same name that generated the view (i.e. your `GetForm()` method)

Comment: Thanks That made it better :D @StephenMuecke

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your input with type="submit" is submitting the form. This is the standard behaviour for HTML-forms. 
Change the input's type to type="button":

```
<input id="Send" type="button" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" />
```

Then change the event in jQuery to "click":

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#subject').on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var selectedVal = $('#subject').val();
      $.ajax({
          url: "ContactUs/GetForm",
          type: "POST",
          data: { searchValue: selectedVal },
          async: true,
          success: function (data) {
              $('#renderForms').empty();
              $('#renderForms').append(data);                  
          },
          error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
              alert("An error has occured!!! " + xhr.status + " && " + xhr.responseText);
          }
      });
  }; etc...
```

Comment: I'm sorry but maybe I must have been writing something wrong because the input button should not be activated with the Jquery script. 
but the Jquery script is accidentally activating the method the input button should activate.

Comment: I've added additional information so you should hopefully be able to see what I intended.